# what is the meaning of intensity order in image processing?

Tags: feature-extraction, gradient

I'm reading this [article](http://vision.ia.ac.cn/Students/bfan/mrogh.htm). This article explains a new feature descriptor such as Sift and Surf and it's name is **MROGH**.

In a part of this article, there is this sentence:

```
In our work, sample points are segmented based on their intensity orders
and their gradients are then pooled for each segment.
```

> My question is:
>
> - what is the meaning of **intensity order** and **local intensity** of a point in image?

thanks,

---

**Edit:**

@Yves Daoust linked me [here](http://homepages.inf.ed.ac.uk/rbf/HIPR2/histgram.htm) and that is my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The explanation seems to rest in that quote from the paper: "Specifically,
we first sort sample points in the support region according
to their intensities. Then we divide them into  segments
equally according to their orders. Finally, gradient information
of the sample points in each segment are pooled,
and the gradient orientation histograms in these  segments
are concatenated to form the representation of this support
region."

Comment: He says: " we first sort sample points in the support region according to **their intensities**". How we can sort points according to their intensities? How we can **calculate** the intensity of some points? and what's the meaning of **intensity order**? thank you.

Comment: Thank you. This is my answer.